# Double Linked List delete

Tags: java, data-structures

A double linked list delete method but it is not deleting the number provided to it.

```
Node node = head;
tail = head;
node = node.next;
while (tail != null) {
    tail.next = node;
    node.previous = tail;
    if (tail.data == data)
        break;
    tail = tail.next;
    node = node.next;
}
tail.previous = node.previous;
node.previous = tail.previous;
```

Comment: why do you need to use `tail` here? besides you're performing nullcheck for tail but your node is actually going to be null before tail and you never check it

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. So please [perge, perge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perge#Latin).

Comment: tail node helps in keeping eye on previous node whereas node helps in next node so after breaking the loop we can use both the node to be deleted as well as the node to be shifted to

Comment: tail node helps in keeping eye on previous node whereas node helps in next node so after breaking the loop we can use both the node to be deleted as well as the node to be shifted to

Comment: why do you need `tail` to keep an eye on previous node? you have `previous` pointer for that

Comment: without using tail node        "Node node = head;
        while(node!=null)
        {
            if(node.data == data)
            { break;}
            node = node.next;
        }
        node.next.previous = node.previous.next;
        node.previous.next = node.next.previous;"

Comment: What type is `data` ?

Comment: data is of int type

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be modifying `next` and `previous` until you have found the node of interest.  Oddly you are modifying (on the left of assignment) both every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following logic

```
    node = head;
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.data == data){
            //now you want to delete node
            if(node.previous != null) node.previous.next = node.next;
            if(node.next != null) node.next.previous = node.previous;
            return true; //found 
        }        
        node = node.next;
    }
    return false; //not found
```